# which port to open for gmail TLS in python smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I tried to do the following:

```
import smtplib
smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
```

I got the error: `socket.error: [Errno 10060]`

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

after some digging I have a feeling that my firewall is the blame.
I tried to open port `587` (on a port forwarding to my machine) and still no luck

Is there a different port for the response that I need to open?

Comment: It depends on how you configure your server.

Comment: Assuming your firewall is just a generic home router doing NAT, you really shouldn't need to modify anything on that end.  Your client will open a socket which will be NAT'ed automatically; unless you were trying to run something where the server opened a socket back to you (like the older version of FTP), you shouldn't need to configure anything.  Are you doing this some where a proxy would be an issue?  Can you ping smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: well, apparently the firewall is faulty and blocks it although it is configured not to.
thank you all, I'll close the question

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with your machine/network. I can connect without any problems:

```
In [1]: import smtplib

In [2]: smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
Out[2]: <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x104519d40>
```

Maybe a proxy issue?